# Copy OpenCV IplImage or Mat into Freeimage FIBITMAP

Tags: opencv, freeimage

I need to exchange data between FreeImage (FIBITMAP) and OpenCV format (IplImage and/or Mat). I'm fine with getting data from a FIBITMAP into an IplImage or Mat since FreeImage gives you a function FreeImage_GetScanLine which you can set the OPenCV imageData ptr equal to.

However, I'm stuck on how to do the reverse, i.e. once I have an OpenCV image, how do I get its data into a FreeImage image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be a little careful just copying the data pointer, a lot of image formats have padding to start each new line on eg a 4byte boundary.

If your image has a GetScanLine() function then it's probably safer to make an empty plImage*/cv::Mat and memcopy each row with the pointer returned from GetScanLine() and the .ptr() member of cv::MAt

```
cv::Mat &src        
int srcRowBytes = width  * src.elemSize();

for (int ih=0;ih<height;ih++) {
    memcpy(dest.pointer_to_row(ih),src.ptr(ih),srcRowBytes);
}
```

Comment: both `IplImage` and `cv::Mat` have a row-step that is there exactly for this reason (padding).

Comment: Yes but can you find out what Freeebitmap is using for it's stepping?

Comment: There's a function FreeImage_GetPitch that returns the width of the image in bytes, same as OpenCV's stepWidth. I'll try this soon and let you guys know if it pans out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more detailed code for the conversion.  There are many image data types in either library, I tried supporting most common ones.  This assumes you are passing a cv::Mat as the source.  FreeImage has the view perspective of lower left!

```
/*  These are openCV types
#define CV_8U   0
#define CV_8S   1
#define CV_16U  2
#define CV_16S  3
#define CV_32S  4
#define CV_32F  5
#define CV_64F  6
*/

/*  these are FI types
FIT_UNKNOWN = 0,    // unknown type
FIT_BITMAP  = 1,    // standard image           : 1-, 4-, 8-, 16-, 24-, 32-bit
FIT_UINT16  = 2,    // array of unsigned short  : unsigned 16-bit
FIT_INT16   = 3,    // array of short           : signed 16-bit
FIT_UINT32  = 4,    // array of unsigned long   : unsigned 32-bit
FIT_INT32   = 5,    // array of long            : signed 32-bit
FIT_FLOAT   = 6,    // array of float           : 32-bit IEEE floating point
FIT_DOUBLE  = 7,    // array of double          : 64-bit IEEE floating point
FIT_COMPLEX = 8,    // array of FICOMPLEX       : 2 x 64-bit IEEE floating point
FIT_RGB16   = 9,    // 48-bit RGB image         : 3 x 16-bit
FIT_RGBA16  = 10,   // 64-bit RGBA image        : 4 x 16-bit
FIT_RGBF    = 11,   // 96-bit RGB float image   : 3 x 32-bit IEEE floating point
FIT_RGBAF   = 12    // 128-bit RGBA float image : 4 x 32-bit IEEE floating point

*/

if(_dib)  // get rid of the current dib. 
    FreeImage_Unload(_dib);


int width  = src.size().width;
int height = src.size().height;

switch(src.type())
{
case CV_8U  :{_dib = FreeImage_AllocateT(FIT_BITMAP,width, height, 8) ;}break;  // 8  bit grayscale
case CV_8UC3:{_dib = FreeImage_AllocateT(FIT_BITMAP,width, height, 24);}break;  // 24 bit RGB
case CV_16U :{_dib = FreeImage_AllocateT(FIT_UINT16,width, height, 16);}break;  // 16 bit grayscale
case CV_16S :{_dib = FreeImage_AllocateT(FIT_INT16 ,width, height, 16);}break;
case CV_32S :{_dib = FreeImage_AllocateT(FIT_INT32 ,width, height, 32);}break;
case CV_32F :{_dib = FreeImage_AllocateT(FIT_FLOAT ,width, height, 32);}break;
case CV_64F :{_dib = FreeImage_AllocateT(FIT_DOUBLE,width, height, 32);}break;
default:ASSERT(FALSE);
}

if(_dib==NULL)
    return FALSE;


int srcRowBytes = width  * src.elemSize();

for (int ih=0;ih<height;ih++) 
{
    BYTE* ptr2Line = FreeImage_GetScanLine(_dib,(height-1)-ih);
    memcpy(ptr2Line,src.ptr(ih),srcRowBytes);
}
_bHasChanged = TRUE;

return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't mind the copy, you can just create an `IplImage*`/`cv::Mat` header for the FIBITMAP and then copy (using the opencv function), like this:

```
cv::Mat src; // your source image
FIBITMAP whatever; // allocate space for your FIBITMAP here
cv::Mat wrapper(height, width, CV_8UC3, ptr_from_FIBITMAP, step);
src.copyTo(wrapper);
```