# Reading gif color image with FreeImage library and convert it to OpenCV Mat

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, freeimage

Colors got lost when I convert a gif color image  in Freeimage FIBITMAP* fromat to OpenCV Mat. I use opencv 3.1.0.

1. I read A1.gif with this code:

   ```
   FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT format = FreeImage_GetFileType(imgPath.c_str(), 0);
   FIBITMAP *image = FreeImage_Load(format, imgPath.c_str());
   ```

[image: A1.gif]
A1.gif

2. If I convert image to OpenCV Mat with this code and show it, I see A2.jpg. **Why OpenCV show this image instead of A1.gif?**

   ```
   Mat img(FreeImage_GetHeight(image), FreeImage_GetWidth(image), CV_8UC3, FreeImage_GetBits(image), FreeImage_GetPitch(image));

   namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   imshow("Display window", img);
   ```

[image: A2.jpg]
A2.jpg

3. If I Change **CV_8UC3** to **CV_8UC1**, I see A3.jpg.

[image: A3.jpg]
A3.jpg

**For other formats like jpg or tif the problem dose not exist. what is the solution?**

Another example is B1.gif, **Segmentation fault for second stage** and B3.jpg.

[image: B1.gif]
B1.gif(It seems that when I uploaded this photo alpha channel was removed.)

[image: B3.gif]
B3.gif

I saw this two post but they have the same problem.

[Convert FreeImage FIBITMAP format to OpenCV Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814451/convert-freeimage-fibitmap-format-to-opencv-mat)

[c++ - FreeImage+OpenCV - 16bit image get distorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866822/c-freeimageopencv-16bit-image-get-distorted)

---

Update: I found the solution.

The correct code for loading gif with FreeImage and Converting it to OpenCV Mat:

```
FIBITMAP *image = FreeImage_Load(format, GifImagePath);
RGBQUAD *pal = FreeImage_GetPalette(image);
unsigned width = FreeImage_GetWidth(image);
unsigned height = FreeImage_GetHeight(image);

FIBITMAP *tmp = FreeImage_Allocate(width, height, 24);
BYTE *tmp_bits = FreeImage_GetBits(tmp);

for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        BYTE t;

        //FreeImage_GetPixelIndex(image,x, y, &t);//safer, in animated gif
        t = img_bits[x+y*height];//Probably faster

        RGBQUAD color = pal[t];

        //FreeImage_SetPixelColor(tmp, x, y, &color);//safer, in animated 
        //Probably faster
        tmp_bits[(x+y*height)*3 +FI_RGBA_RED] = color.rgbRed;
        tmp_bits[(x+y*height)*3+FI_RGBA_GREEN] = color.rgbGreen;
        tmp_bits[(x+y*height)*3+FI_RGBA_BLUE] = color.rgbBlue;
    }
}

Mat img(FreeImage_GetHeight(tmp), FreeImage_GetWidth(tmp), CV_8UC3, FreeImage_GetBits(tmp), FreeImage_GetPitch(tmp));

namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Display window", img);
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes. Your answer is correct but I at first I couldn't implement it with FreeImage, now I managed to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not handling the images correctly - the images that are problematic to you have two things in common:

- they are **palettised**, and,
- they have an **alpha** layer

As they are palettised, the numbers in the bitmap do not represent colours, they represent indices into the palette. I don't use, or know, **FreeImage**, but you need to get the palette and then iterate through the bitmap and instead of taking the values from the bitmap and putting them into the `Mat`, you need to use the values in the bitmap as indices into the palette and take the colour at the specified offset and put that into the `Mat`. There may be a `ConvertToType()` sort of function that will do that for you - in which case you will need to convert from a **palette** type to a **true-colour** type.

Secondly, you need to deal with the transparency. If your image has transparency, you will need a 4-channel `Mat` in **OpenCV**, which has B,G,R and Alpha/Transparency.

By comparison, JPEG images do not contain a palette and cannot contain transparency - hence they work in your code :-)

If you are on Linux, you will have **ImageMagick** installed and you can get it for macOS and Windows easily enough - it's free. You can then look at your images and see what I mean:

```
identify -verbose drummer.gif | more
```

**Output**

```
Image: drummer.gif
  Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
  Mime type: image/gif
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 800x600+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: PaletteAlpha             <--- Palette and transparency
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
    Alpha: 1-bit                 <--- 4th transparency layer
```

As a temporary fix, you could try converting the drummer to `PPM` which does not support transparency but which **FreeImage** can read:

```
convert drummer.gif drummer.ppm
```

Or

```
convert drummer.gif drummer.jpg
```

Comment: ah.. ImageMagick.. the solution to, well, everything ;)

Comment: @Miki Nah, there once was an answer where I had to use Perl. And one with GNU Parallel ;-)

Comment: @Miki Do you know suitable freeimage convert function?

Comment: @Iman No, I wrote one a while ago (you already saw it since it's linked in your question)... It wasn't supposed to work for all edge cases. You can, however, make your own function based on that, adding the missing code to handle this case.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. I'll check your solution.