# OpenCV image conversion goes wrong

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an algorithm that does some stuff. Among them, there is a conversion that works fine if I'm working on a `CV_8UC3` image but goes wrong if the file type is `C_16UC3`.
This is some code:

```
//new image is created
Mat3w img(100,100,Vec3w(1000,0,0));
//Image Conversion - ERROR!
cv::Mat inputSource;
//saving the image here will work
img.convertTo(inputSource, CV_64FC3);
//saving the image here will not work -> black image
```

The problem is that the `CV_16UC3` image's processing result is an image of the right dimensions but fully black.
The problem is in the conversion because saving the image right before will give a legit one while saving it right after will give an almost completely white one.

**EDIT:**

I made some changes: cut off some useless code and added the inputSource declaration.
Now, while I was trying stuff, I arrived at the conclusion that either I haven't understood the CV Types, or something strange is happening.
I always thought that the number in the type was indicating the number of bits per channel. So, in my head, `CV_16UC3` is a 3 channel with 16bits per channel. That idea is strengthened by the fact that the image I save during as tests (before the img.convertTo) actually had matching bits per channel number. The strange thing, is that the saved inputSource (type `CV_64FC3`) is an 8bpc image.

What's am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I made some edit!
The CV_MAKTYPE was there because of copy/paste error. In the code it belongs to an old conversion line.
The relevant code is pretty much the one up there. I create the Mat, it gets passed as an argument to a function that declare inputSource and convert the image in this new Mat.

Comment: @pedro what kind of error message do you get?

Comment: if no error but just imwrite writes wrong image, see that http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite doesnt want you to save floating point images. instead try to display the mat with imshow (values between 0 = black and 1 = white in each channel) or print values to terminal.

Comment: Ok, I think I achived making it work :)
The problem, probably, was that the algorithm set a 255 bit pixel upper bound limit but didn't forced the convertion to 8bit. So, loading a 16bit image messed up everything.
Now it works with 16 bit :)
It doesn't whit 32bit's images but that's not really a problem. I'll try later but I don't really mind. 
Thank you again! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get confused with the way `imwrite` and `imread` work in OpenCV. From the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56&gsc.tab=0)

**imwrite**

The function `imwrite` saves the image to the specified file. The image format is chosen based on the filename extension (see `imread()` for the list of extensions). Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (`CV_16U`) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function. If the format, depth or channel order is different, use `Mat::convertTo()` , and `cvtColor()` to convert it before saving. Or, use the universal `FileStorage` I/O functions to save the image to XML or YAML format.

**imread**

The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. Possible flags are:

- IMREAD_UNCHANGED : If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped).
- IMREAD_GRAYSCALE : If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image.
- IMREAD_COLOR : If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.
- IMREAD_ANYDEPTH : If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.
- IMREAD_ANYCOLOR : If set, the image is read in any possible color format.

So for your case, `CV_16U` are saved without conversion, while `CV_64F` is converted and saved as `CV_8U`. If you want to store `double` data, you should use `FileStorage`.
You should also take care to use `imread` the image with the appropriate flag.

This example should clarify:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Create a 16-bit 3 channel image
    Mat3w img16UC3(100, 200, Vec3w(1000, 0, 0));
    img16UC3(Rect(0, 0, 20, 50)) = Vec3w(0, 2000, 0);

    // Convert to 64-bit (double) 3 channel image
    Mat3d img64FC3;
    img16UC3.convertTo(img64FC3, CV_64FC3);

    // Save to disk
    imwrite("16UC3.png", img16UC3); // No conversion
    imwrite("64FC3.png", img64FC3); // Converted to CV_8UC3

    FileStorage fout("64FC3.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fout << "img" << img64FC3; // No conversion
    fout.release();


    Mat img_maybe16UC3_a = imread("16UC3.png" /*, IMREAD_COLOR*/);  // Will be CV_8UC3
    Mat img_maybe16UC3_b = imread("16UC3.png", IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);    // Will be CV_16UC1
    Mat img_maybe16UC3_c = imread("16UC3.png", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);   // Will be CV_16UC3 

    Mat img_maybe64FC3_a = imread("64FC3.png" /*, IMREAD_COLOR*/);  // Will be CV_8UC3
    Mat img_maybe64FC3_b = imread("64FC3.png", IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);    // Will be CV_8UC1
    Mat img_maybe64FC3_c = imread("64FC3.png", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);   // Will be CV_8UC3

    Mat img_mustbe64FC3;
    FileStorage fin("64FC3.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    fin["img"] >> img_mustbe64FC3; // Will be CV_64FC3
    fin.release();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok so, if I get it right, it is pointless to follow how the program is going by saving the image right after the conversion using imwrite because it will always get stored bad?
For what concern imread, the original code used it (with CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR as flags), but I had to use FreeImage because I need to load hdr/pfm/pbf/tiff images too..

Comment: Anyway, the algorithm will always save 8bit/channel images because that's how it works; so after I achieve loading the image I want to filter (and I did it) it should work..right?

Comment: @pedro `imwrite` saves images as RGB, nothing wrong about it. You can work with any type you prefer, just keep in mind that if you save the result as an image, the image will be RGB. If you want to store actual values, use a `FileStorage`.