# Mapping data types of two different libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, types, mapping, type-conversion

I need to convert the image data types of OpenCV into the types of another 3rd party library and vice versa. What is a nice way to do this?

Currently I'm using `boost::bimap` but maybe theres is a cleaner solution. My biggest problem is, that OpenCV defines all types with header macros like this:

```
#define CV_8U   0
#define CV_8S   1
#define CV_16U  2
#define CV_16S  3
#define CV_32S  4
#define CV_32F  5
#define CV_64F  6

#define CV_8UC1 CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,1)
#define CV_8UC2 CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,2)
```

while the other 3rd party library defines its types via enums:

```
typedef enum {
PF_UNKNOWN                  = 0,
PF_8BIT                     = 10,
PF_GREYSCALE_8              = 11,
PF_RGB_8                    = 12, 
PF_16BIT                    = 20,
PF_GREYSCALE_10             = 21,
PF_GREYSCALE_12             = 22,
PF_GREYSCALE_14             = 23,
PF_GREYSCALE_16             = 24,
PF_RGB_444                  = 25,
PF_RGB_555                  = 26,
PF_RGB_565                  = 27,
PF_RGBA_4444                = 28
.....
} tPixelFormat;
```

As a result I'm hardcoding the OpenCV values when creating the map (which seems to be a very bad approach).

Comment: does that enum use any rule for assigning types to values? You should show the enum values too. Fort he OpenCV macros you can look here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h

Comment: @Micka I added the missing data.

Comment: Can you show your code that builds up the bmap?

Comment: You have no other choice in this situation than to hardcode the type mapping, as there is no common logic in the OpenCV and tPixelFormat numbering.

Comment: You basically need to take into account all possible cases. You can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31878378/5008845) for a similar question